# Setting widgets visibility when two widgets is one above the other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to create one fragment like below.

Clicking on `Need Cash TextView` will Change the containing Layout which will have two buttons `Cancel` & `Meet` and toggle in between these views.

But when I click on Need Cash call `toggleVisibility()` function is making the `Need Cash` invisible but not showing `Cancel | Meet`.

What mistakes I am doing in this process?

```
|----------------------|        =>        |----------------------|
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|                      |        =>        |                      |
|----------------------|        =>        |----------------------|
|     Need Cash        |        =>        | Cancel  |   Meet     |
|----------------------|        =>        |----------------------|







@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv_need_cash:
                toggleVisibility();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_need_cash_cancel:
            toggleVisibility();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tv_need_cash_cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.tv_need_cash_lets_meet:
            toggleVisibility();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tv_need_cash_lets_meet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

public void toggleVisibility() {
    if(needCashTv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        //needCashTv.setEnabled(false);
        needCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frameForNeedCashStuff.bringToFront();

        frameForNeedCashStuff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //cancelNeedCashTv.setEnabled(true);
        cancelNeedCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //letsMeetneedCashTv.setEnabled(true);
        letsMeetneedCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        //needCashTv.setEnabled(true);
        needCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        needCashTv.bringToFront();

        frameForNeedCashStuff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //cancelNeedCashTv.setEnabled(false);
        cancelNeedCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //letsMeetneedCashTv.setEnabled(false);
        letsMeetneedCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    thisView.invalidate();
}


.....................OTHER WIDGETS ABOVE......................
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameForNeedCashStuff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash_cancel"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash_lets_meet"
            android:text="Let's Meet"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash"
        android:text="@string/need_cash"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
.....................OTHER WIDGETS BELOW......................
```

**EDIT**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View thisView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
return thisView;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

**Fragment view before clicking which is showing the Keep Cash TextView**

[image: Fragment view before clicking which is showing the Keep Cash TextView]

**Fragment view after clicking which is NOT showing the 'Cancel' and 'Meet' TextViews**

[image: Fragment view after clicking which is NOT showing the 'Cancel' and 'Meet' TextViews]

**EDIT 3 **
Given id to outer RelativeLayout and invalidated it

```
public void toggleVisibility() {
        if(needCashTv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            //needCashTv.setEnabled(false);
            needCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            frameForNeedCashStuff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //cancelNeedCashTv.setEnabled(true);
            cancelNeedCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //letsMeetneedCashTv.setEnabled(true);
            letsMeetneedCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            frameForNeedCashStuff.bringToFront();
        }
        else {
            //needCashTv.setEnabled(true);
            needCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            needCashTv.bringToFront();

            frameForNeedCashStuff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //cancelNeedCashTv.setEnabled(false);
            cancelNeedCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //letsMeetneedCashTv.setEnabled(false);
            letsMeetneedCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ((ViewGroup)frameForNeedCashStuff2.getParent()).invalidate();
        //thisView.invalidate();
    }
```

Working code after fix
**EDIT 4**

```
public void toggleVisibility() {
    if(needCashTv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        needCashTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        frameForNeedCashStuff2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        needCashTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        needCashTv.bringToFront();

        frameForNeedCashStuff2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    ((ViewGroup)frameForNeedCashStuff.getParent()).invalidate();
}


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameForNeedCashStuff">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/frameForNeedCashStuff2">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash_cancel"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
        android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash_lets_meet"
        android:text="Let's Meet"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
        android:textColor="@color/White"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_need_cash"
    android:text="@string/need_cash"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_sizes_small"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try to invalidate the parent view and not the actual view.
((ViewGroup)getParent()).invalidate();

Comment: @bastienpinaquy Can you please confirm whose parent view, Layout or of widgets.

Comment: Tried this 
        `((ViewGroup)frameForNeedCashStuff.getParent()).invalidate();` but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Use FrameLayout as the root layout instead of toplevel RelativeLayout. Make the inner RelativeLayout and TextView width and height as match_parent.

Comment: Or use ViewSwitcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RelativeLayout` wrapping the `TextView`s (`tv_need_cash_cancel` and `tv_need_cash_lets_meet` is set to 'gone'.

It will never show if you just toggle the visibility of the child views.

Also are you sure you need the `View.invalidate()`? If you're just toggling the visibility, it's not necessary.

Comment: calling thisView.invalidate();

Comment: thisView is in-fact the view reference returned by inflater

Comment: Did you check, what it actually does for you? I really don't think it's necessary. And did you try setting the `RelativeLayout` to visible, as i suggested?

Comment: I still see the `RelativeLayout`, without an id, as 'gone', you're setting the wrong views as visible.

Comment: Yes,  I was invalidating wrong RelativeLayout... I was invalidating the inner RelativeLayout. But in my fragment xml I have other layout also . Do I need to invalidate the layout of topmost layout???

Comment: But still no success

Comment: You don't need to invalidate anything. Just give that `RelativeLayout` an id, inflate it and toggle the visibility of that Container, instead of toggling the visibility of those TextViews. I would also recommend using a `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: `frameForNeedCashStuff` is not the `RelativeLayout` i'm talking about. If you set that to invisible, all the childs will be. I'm talking about the `RelativeLayout` inside, the one holding the 2 `TextView`'s, it's set to 'gone', and you're never changing it to 'visible', so it won't ever show anything.

Comment: Let me change the Layout to FrameLayout

Comment: I got my mistake... Thanks a lot for your time. Thanks.

I have updated my working code in EDIT 4 section of the question.